# CoreData Fetched Property referring to a different entity

Tags: ios, core-data, fetched-property, fetched-properties

I have a CoreData Entity named `List` it has a Relationship to an Entity `Address`. This is a one-to-many relationship seeing as an `Address` can be only be one `List`.

`Address` entities have an Attribute `flag` which is an `Integer 16`.

Is there a way for me to define a `Fetched Property` in the `List` entity with a count of all related `Address` entities that have their `flag` set to 1? What would the predicate look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this:

Create a fetch request for the `List` entity and set its predicate to:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"address.flag == %@", @1]`

Also don't forget to prefetch relationship so you don't encounter any cache misses.

Comment: yes, I know it is possible with a fetch request. I was wondering if I could have it as a fetch property, so that I wouldn't have to constantly call up the requests and instead just call an `attribute` of the entity `List`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't access a Managed Object and/or its relationship(s) without a fetch. But you can fetch only the attributes you're interested in. If that's the case, tell me and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I'm aware of fetching only single attributes. What I was looking for something that would make something like the following possible: `myList.countAllFlagged` and get a NSNumber of all `addresses` in `list` that have `flag` set to `1`. I guess I'll have to stick with my fetchRequest.

Comment: Another way you could do what you want would be to create an Integer attribute in your `List` entity named `count` or whatever and increment it every time you add a new address to that `List`. You could do this in a convenience method in a category of your `List` Managed Object.

Comment: thought of that one too, was just too "scared" of possible race-conditions on asynchronous-tasks. Also though about adding a custom method to my `mogenerator` generated `NSObjects` that performs the fetch for me, so that I can keep my code cleaner.

Comment: I think that something like this could also work: `int addressCount = [[ list valueForKeyPath:@"address.@count"] intValue]` or even better call the `count` method on your `Address` relationship attribute set but you must first filter/extract the values you're interested in. Check NSSet and NSCountedSet classes.